# Помогите исправить ошибку с установкой билиотек Python3

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pip

вот ошибка
[image: ERROR: error [WinError87] Параметр задан неверно while executing command python setup.py egg_info ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError87] Параметр задан неверно]

> ERROR: error [WinError87] Параметр задан неверно while executing
>   command python setup.py egg_info    ERROR: Could not install packages
>   due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError87] Параметр задан неверно

Comment: Можешь попробовать еще раз, только теперь с `-vvv`? `pip3 install vk_api -vvv` и добавь текст лога в ответ.

Comment: Попробуйте перезапусить Visual Studio Code. Мне помогло.